# Override bind for existing session to make it join external transaction?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

Below example of opening external transaction:

```
import random
from asyncio import current_task
from functools import wraps

from fastapi import APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_scoped_session, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Mapped, mapped_column
    
router = APIRouter()

engine = create_async_engine("url", echo=True)


scoped_session = async_scoped_session(
    async_sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=False, autoflush=False),
    scopefunc=current_task
)

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class Country(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, index=True)
    code: Mapped[str]
    name: Mapped[str]



class TestTransactionDataSchema(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str


@router.post("/test-external-transaction")
async def test_external_transaction(data: TestTransactionDataSchema): 
    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        session = scoped_session(bind=connection)
        country = Country(code=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)), name=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)))
        session.add(country)
        await session.commit()
        country = Country(code=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)), name=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)))
        session.add(country)
        await session.commit()
        await scoped_session.remove()
    return data
```

External transaction is being opened and session joins it:

```
2024-03-12 12:30:36,622 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-03-12 12:30:36,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO countries (code, name, is_active) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, $2::VARCHAR, $3::BOOLEAN) RETURNING countries.id
2024-03-12 12:30:36,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00017s] ('54573', '98157', True)
2024-03-12 12:30:36,696 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO countries (code, name, is_active) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, $2::VARCHAR, $3::BOOLEAN) RETURNING countries.id
2024-03-12 12:30:36,696 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.005118s ago] ('17932', '95985', True)
2024-03-12 12:30:36,698 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

P.S. Session does not open its own transaction on each commit.

Now I'd like to move transactions management (for some reasons) into a decorator `atomic`:

```
import random
from asyncio import current_task
from functools import wraps

from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_scoped_session, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Mapped, mapped_column
    
router = APIRouter()

engine = create_async_engine("url", echo=True)


scoped_session = async_scoped_session(
    async_sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=False, autoflush=False),
    scopefunc=current_task
)

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class Country(Base):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(autoincrement=True, primary_key=True, index=True)
    code: Mapped[str]
    name: Mapped[str]


async def get_session():
    session = scoped_session()
    yield session
    await scoped_session.remove()


def atomic(func):

    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        async with engine.begin() as connection:
            session = scoped_session()
            # session already in scoped scoped_session.registry.registry
            session.bind = connection
            result = await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return result

    return wrapper


class TestTransactionDataSchema(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str


@router.post("/test-external-transaction")
@atomic
async def test_external_transaction(data: TestTransactionDataSchema, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    country = Country(code=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)), name=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)))
    session.add(country)
    await session.commit()
    country = Country(code=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)), name=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)))
    session.add(country)
    await session.commit()
    return data
```

As far as I could guess I need to override bind for the session that is in scoped registry. But `session.bind = connection` does not work because at each commit session opens new transaction:

```
2024-03-12 12:41:17,265 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-03-12 12:41:17,424 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-03-12 12:41:17,426 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO countries (code, name, is_active) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, $2::VARCHAR, $3::BOOLEAN) RETURNING countries.id
2024-03-12 12:41:17,426 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00019s] ('20269', '40922', True)
2024-03-12 12:41:17,431 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2024-03-12 12:41:17,435 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-03-12 12:41:17,436 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO countries (code, name, is_active) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR, $2::VARCHAR, $3::BOOLEAN) RETURNING countries.id
2024-03-12 12:41:17,436 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.01033s ago] ('67350', '57030', True)
2024-03-12 12:41:17,439 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2024-03-12 12:41:17,441 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

This means that session does not join external transaction.

My goal is to manage transaction outside a wrapped view.

How to make session join external transaction?

Comment: Have you tried `session = await session_factory(bind=connection)`?

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that the session joins the external transaction and does not open a new transaction on each commit, you need to make sure that the session is bound to the external connection correctly. In your `atomic` decorator, you are currently creating a new session inside the decorator, which does not bind to the external connection.

You can modify the `atomic` decorator to accept an external session and bind it to the scoped session.

```py
from functools import wraps

from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_scoped_session, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker

router = APIRouter()

engine = create_async_engine("url", echo=True)

# Create an async session factory
SessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)


class Country(Base):
    id: int
    code: str
    name: str


class TestTransactionDataSchema(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str


async def get_session():
    async with SessionLocal() as session:
        yield session


def atomic(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        async with engine.begin() as connection:
            async with SessionLocal() as session:
                session.bind = connection
                result = await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return result

    return wrapper


@router.post("/test-external-transaction")
@atomic
async def test_external_transaction(data: TestTransactionDataSchema, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    # Your transaction logic here
    country = Country(code=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)), name=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)))
    session.add(country)
    await session.commit()
    country = Country(code=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)), name=str(random.randint(1, 100_000)))
    session.add(country)
    await session.commit()
    return data
```

- The `atomic` decorator now accepts an external session `SessionLocal` created with `async_sessionmaker`.
- Inside the decorator, the external session is bound to the scoped session, ensuring that the session joins the external transaction.
- The view function `test_external_transaction` accepts the session as a dependency using the `Depends` mechanism provided by FastAPI.